# Why is it a good practice to remove PHP files from the htdocs directory?

Tags: php, security

Why is it a good practice to remove PHP files from the htdocs/public directory?
They are being parsed anyway, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are parsed.  However, that is completely dependent on you or the server admin not screwing up the config files.

All it takes is a quick typo in the Apache config before Apache forgets to parse the PHP (I've had this happen).  Since Apache won't know what to do with a PHP file after that, your source code just gets output as plain text, and can be immediately copied.  Heck, it's even cached in the user's browser, so a malicious user can quickly copy all your code and browse it later at their convenience, looking for security holes.

You don't want your source to be visible even for a second.  If you have no code files in the htdocs directory, this can't happen.  They can easily be included into your code from outside the directory however.

Many MVC frameworks use this method of sandboxing for just this purpose.

Answer (score 8):

if PHP files are at some point ***not*** parsed due to a configuration error or, say, a failing interpreter, there is no danger of the source code (and possibly passwords) being revealed to the world as clear text.

Also, human mistakes like renaming a .php file to `.php.bak` are less dangerous that way.

I had this once, years ago, when a colleague, from the Perl world and totally ignorant about PHP, decided to set "[short_open_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)" to "off" on a server we shared, because short_open_tags messed with some XML experiment he had going (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`). *That* was fun! :)

and a second thing:

**Calling includes out of context**

Having includes (i.e. pieces of PHP code that is included elsewhere) under the web root makes you potentially vulnerable to people calling those includes directly, out of context, possibly bypassing security checks and initializations.

If you can't/won't avoid PHP code to reside in the web root, at least be sure to start each file checking whether it is running in the correct context.

Set this in your main script(s):

```
define ("RUNNING_IN_SCRIPT", true);
```

and add this to the 1st line of each include:

```
if (!defined("RUNNING_IN_SCRIPT")) die ("This file cannot be called directly.");
```

Comment: Ah, short_open_tags.  This is precisely the reason people (like me) now say to never use them.  Once bitten, twice shy.

Answer (score 1):

The more executable PHP files you have, the more security risks you also have :

- What if there is a problem in your configuration *(it happens !)*, and the source code of your PHP file containing your database credentials is sent to the browser ?
- what if there is some "bad" thing left in one of those files, you didn't think about, and no-one ever tested ?

The less PHP executable files you have... well, that's a couple of potential problems you don't have to care about.

That's why it's often considered as best to :

- put under the document root only the PHP files that have to be called via Apache *(like `index.php`, for instance)*,
- and put outside of the document root the PHP files that are not accessed directly, but only included by the first ones *(ie, libraries / frameworks, for instance)*.